# Django auth_user_model

Tags: django

I'd like to make auth_user_model login but I need to login with Email and Password. So I thought I can do that if I can save email value in 'username' field.

```
class HeepooUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    allow_phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    date_join = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user = user_form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile = profile_form.save()

            registered = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Wrong access1')

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, "register.html", {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        'registered': registered,
})
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', }),
)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password',)


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HeepooUser
        exclude = ('allow_phone', 'user',)
```

Register.html

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

Could you please help me on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request the email instead of username to the user in your login form in order to use it for loggin him, then just generate a username for that user, you can do it using his email or name.

EDIT:
You only need to generate an username. Let's say that you are requesting name and last name to the user. Let's create a method to generate it.

```
def generate_username(first_name, last_name):
        username = '%s.%s' % (first_name.lower(), last_name.lower())
        username = '{:.29}'.format(username)
        counter = User.objects.filter(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name).count()
        if counter > 0:
            username += '%s' % (counter + 1)
        return username
```

Then you can use it on your view.

```
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.username = generate_username(first_name, last_name)
        .....
```

If you don't want to request first name or last name, you can generate the username using his email too.

Comment: I added forms.py Could you please let me know how I can modify?